# Jacoco maven configuration for multi module project when some modules are present in sub directory

Tags: maven, jacoco

My Project contains following structure

```
pom.xml
|
|
-----sub module A pom.xml 
|
|
-----sub module B pom.xml
|
|
-----sub module plugins/C pom.xml
|
| 
-----sub module plugins/D pom.xml
```

I have configured Main pom like this

```
<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>plugins/C</module>
    <module>plugins/D</module>
</modules>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I am running "mvn verify" jacoco reports are getting generated only for module A & B. For module plugin/C and plugin/D Jacoco is not executed hence no reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not about `jacoco-maven-plugin`, but about [aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) and [inheritance](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) in Maven.

Given `example/pom.xml`

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>plugins/C</module>
  </modules>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

specifies that `example/A` and `example/plugins/C` should be built as part of build of `example`, but doesn't specify anything about inheritance of configuration of plugins, properties, etc.

For inheritance in `example/plugins/C/pom.xml` from `example/pom.xml`, the first one should declare the second one as `parent`:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../..</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>C</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

In such case configuration of plugins will be inherited and they will be executed:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T21:39:06+02:00)
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building C 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:prepare-agent (default) @ C ---
...
```

P.S. Latest as of today version of JaCoCo is 0.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

Add a another pom.xml for your plugins folder, let it inherit from your parent pom and define C & D as a submodule there and remove the modules from your parent pom and add the plugins folder instead. And don’t forget to change the parent pom from C & D to the plugin pom, that should do it.